# $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$, measurable, and $\int_{[0,1]}f(x)dx=y\implies m\{x:f(x)>\frac{y}{2}\}\geq\frac{y}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Question: Suppose $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ is a measurable function such that $\int_0^1f(x)dx=y$.  Prove that $m\{x:f(x)>\frac{y}{2}\}\geq\frac{y}{2}$.

My thoughts: Since we have $\int_0^1f(x)dx=y\implies \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1f(x)dx=\frac{y}{2}$.  Now, I was hoping to be able to split the integral bounds and consider $\int f$ over $\{x:f(x)>\frac{y}{2}\}$ and over $\{x:f(x)\leq\frac{y}{2}\}$, and somehow use Markov's inequality in there somewhere.  I think I have something off though and I am not sure if I can do what I am saying, or even if it is correct.  Any suggestions, ideas, etc. are greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Contradiction and dividing integral in 2 parts ruins given equality.

Comment: So, assume the integral does not equal $y$, and then split into two parts?

Comment: Added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A = \{x:f(x)>\frac{y}{2}\}$ and $m(A)<\frac{y}{2}$. Also lets denote $B = \{x:f(x)\leqslant\frac{y}{2}\}$. Now we have
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1} = \int\limits_{A}+ \int\limits_{B}$$
For first we use that $f \leqslant 1$ and $m(A)<\frac{y}{2}$. For second we have estimation $\leqslant \frac{y}{2}$. So, sum cannot be $y$.

Comment: why is $\int_{B} f \leq  y/2$ ?

Comment: $m(B) \leqslant 1$ and $f \leqslant \frac{y}{2}$ on $B$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would anything have changed if say $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,\infty]$?

Comment: For brought way $f \leqslant 1$ is essential. In general case, may be, helpful will be to split bounded case from unbounded.